# On setting bounties

Tags: discussion, bounty

I was just wondering if a person with 40 reputation points could offer a bounty worth 50. I just saw this. So suppose if I answer and he accepts it as correct, would he have -10 reputation points then?

[image: Is it for real?]

Comment: You lose the rep when you *set* the bounty, not when it is awarded. You can also never have less than one rep.

Answer (score 3):

When you set a bounty, you instantly lose reputation points. So that doesn't mean that a 40 reputation user can set a 50-rep bounty; instead, the user who set the bounty originally had 40 + 50 = 90 reputation.